# Android - dynamically request camera access

Tags: android, permissions, camera

I want to add the following permissions to my Android app, but doing so would block about 500 devices supported in my current build:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android:hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Is there any way to conditionally request access to the camera for some OS's and not others?  Is the only way to achieve this to release two apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app *uses* the camera **but** it's not a mandatory feature, you can set `required` attribute to `false`, as you did with your second feature.-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android:hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Sweet!  Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Wish I get a coin every time it happens to me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   Storage permition also insert over here in manifest file 

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```